# XNA small noise when sound starts or stops playing

Tags: c#, audio, xna

I made a small application that plays .wav  files when you press keys, essentially trying to play music on the keyboard, but there is some noise from the speakers when I release a key, and I believe also when I press it. The .wav file is just a sinusoidal wave, so I don't think that it's the source of the problem, any clues as to what causes the sound and any workarounds? The noise is similar to the momentary static you gen when you plug in headphones or something similar.

Comment: Have you tried just playing audio on your pc (both the file in question and other audio)? do your speakers do this normally?

Comment: VLC shows no such behavior with mp3 files and YouTube plays fine both in flash and HTML5

Comment: Maybe provide us with some code snippets and tell us what you have tried so far to resolve this issue

Comment: I really haven't tried anything because I just use the `SoundEffect` class and it's `Play()` function... You can also manually create a stream I believe, but it's a bit of a fuss

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this problem, you have to capture two KeyboardStates.

```
KeyboardState oldState;
KeyboardState currentState;

public void Load()
{
    oldstate = Keyboard.GetState();
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    currentState = Keyboard.GetState();
    //Example below

    if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space)
    && currentState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    {
       //Play Sound
    }
    oldState = currentState;
}
```

What this will do is make sure that the key being pressed's old state was up and the new one is down. This will stop the sound from playing over and over again. Then at the end of the update loop, it will set the currentState as the oldState and start the logic over again.

Comment: Chances are the problem is indeed continuously replaying the file, I sort of had the implementation aimed at avoiding it but I apparently didn't think it through! Will notify on the final success.

Comment: Unfortunately we've just finished semester exams and I have not yet had the opportunity to give it as much time as I wanted - however I did try preventing replaying with a couple of ways and I pretty much made it worse, though I'm sure I'll discover a handful of bugs in there... I have not given up yet, I hope that within the week I will be able to come back with more feedback

Comment: It turns out that what you described does indeed cause noises of a very similar sort. I, personally, had made a mistake in the condition for playing, that is, I was making XNA start playing the sound in every update, so it would abruptly stop playing and start again, not sure about the very specifics, but continuously replaying the sound was my problem. Your answer was correct too though

Comment: I recommend going with my code, it will save you a lot of headache in the future, coming from a person who experienced all of this already.

Comment: My code is similar, I just keep a couple more variables concerning what is already pressed, so I do not restart a key already playing and if it is still pressed in this loop so I can also stop the sound when the key is lifted, I just have a bit more middle work to handle the stopping as well, that's all, thanks for the concern though